# AngularJS input model with sanitized data

Tags: escaping, encode, sanitize

I'm stuck on a simple problem. I've sanitized my form data before I put that on my mysql database through my Laravel 4 RESTful API. So, the sanitized word "são" is stored like "s & #227;o". So far so good. But when I get these data and put it back on text input by ng-model, I'm getting "s & #227;o", not "são".

What I'm missing?

Tks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

use ng-bind-html instead of ng-model.
it will sanitize your data and return the formated text.